# Personal cover letter for visa application for TV-L 13 PhD Position

Tags: visa, germany

I have been offered a Ph.D. position with a TV-L13 (50%) salary. I am in the process of applying for an employment visa (as I am a non-EU citizen). The work contract provided by the university is for a part-time scientific associate. I am unsure of what exactly to write in the personal cover letter (explaining the exact purpose and duration of the stay) for the visa application. Should I write about both the part-time scientific associate position and Ph.D. or only about the part-time scientific associate position?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure this is a question for Expatriates. I wonder if you shouldn't try asking this on Academia. They love this kind of stuff.

Comment: While it is on topic here, it might be also be a bit too primarily opinion based. https://academia.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write both of them. You should make it clear that you pursue your education by doing PhD and in addition to that, you are supported by 50 percent tvl13 position. In addition to that you should attach the invitation letter to your docunents.
In the letter they must clearly provide an approximation of your income.  (You need this support to not put extra money in back and ease your way through the  visa process, I'm not sure if 50% suffices).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. An income of approximately 1800 euros per month is shown in the document. I hope that would be sufficient to ease my way through the employment visa process?

Comment: I think it is sufficient for one person. I don't know exact numbers though. The only issue is that I guess this 1800 is gross not net. However not much tax, insurance, etc. will be added. Again I don't know exact numbers but e.g. if your gross is 4000 you will recieve around 2500 net (+-200 depending to tax class etc). However if your income is 1200 you will recieve around 1100 net. I think yours should be sufficient if tax and insurance doesn't kill it.